# Why does order of inserts to binary tree matter?

Tags: insert, binary-tree, element, operator-precedence

I know that the order does matter when inserting elements into a binary search tree and that elements inserted in different order will lead to different binary tree structures, but I'm not sure how to explain WHY in a coherent way.

Comment: Have you tried doing insertions and watching how the structure changes? That would be the most self explanatory way.

Comment: Would it make sense to say that each insertion depends on the current structure of the tree? I don't know how to explain it clearly enough

Comment: It would, although that won't give a full as to why. Again, I'd say write up a simple binary tree (or use an existing implementation), and literally watch how the structure is different after each insertion depending on the order. I used to do that while writing binary trees for school, and always found it interesting. You could also do it by hand on paper if you have a good understanding of them.

Answer (score 4):

## Another simple explenation

> The first node you add to the BST (binary search tree) will always be the root and cannot be changed after initialization. This fact alone can explain pretty obviously why the ordering matters. Given `N` elements, you have already `N` possible (and more importantly, **different**) BST structures.

### Simple Example

```js
nums = [1,5,10]

/*

TREE1:
1 (root)
 \
  5
   \
   10

TREE2:
   5 (root)
  / \
 1  10

TREE3:
    10 (root)
   /
  5
 /
1

*/
```

### Key Takeaway

- **ordering will affect the balance** of a tree (TREE2 is balanced, TREE1 and TREE3 are not);
- **balancing affects efficiency** for BST operations, e.g. traversal/search:

  - perfectly balanced `O(log_n)` time
  - unbalanced: `O(n)` time (= worst case).

Answer (score 1):

If the insertions are done in an numerical order for a group of numbers, a binary tree becomes a linked list which affects the search performance (it becomes O(n)). The reason being tree is heavily unbalanced.